# HOW TO FIX THIS ERROR The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose i have 2 data sets `db with columns NAME,Ref Amount` & `sp with columns Name,REFERENCE_2,Amount`

I want to check now if a ref in db isin sp if this is true it checks if the amounts are the same if this is true it now returns the whole row in db.

```
b = db["REF_1"].isin(sp["REFERENCE_2"])
for i in range(len(db)):
    if b:
        if db["AMOUNT"] == sp["AMOUNT"]:
            l = db[db["REF_1"].isin(sp["REFERENCE_2"])]
            n = !db[db["REF_1"].isin(sp["REFERENCE_2"])]
        else:
            print("Amounts are different")
    else:
        print("transaction not in suspense")
```

Comment: Please **update the question** with the traceback so we can see where the error is thrown.  I **presume** it’s on the `if b` statement.  Try: `if not b.empty`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the following two lines:

```
if b:
    if db["AMOUNT"] == sp["AMOUNT"]:
```

Both `b` and the result of the comparison `db["AMOUNT"] == sp["AMOUNT"]` are of type `pd.Series', and a series can't be used as a Boolean value in an if.